# Creating a sheet with more than 1000 rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a Google Sheet with more than 1000 rows and am receiving the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid sheets[0].data[0]: Attempting to write row: 1000, beyond the last requested row of: 999",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid sheets[0].data[0]: Attempting to write row: 1000, beyond the last requested row of: 999",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I also tried creating an empty sheet, and then running batch update calls with GridRanges.

```
$range = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$range->setSheetId($sheetId);
$range->setStartRowIndex(0);
$range->setEndRowIndex(sizeof($data));
$range->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$range->setEndColumnIndex(sizeof(array_keys($data[0])));

$cellsRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateCellsRequest();
$cellsRequest->setFields('*');
$cellsRequest->setRange($range);
$cellsRequest->setRows($rowDataArray);

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$request->setUpdateCells($cellsRequest);

$batchUpdate = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdate->setRequests(array($request));
$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdate);
```

When that didn't work, I tried UpdateCellRequests with ranges that were 1000 records in size. That gave me this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"update_cells\" at 'requests[0]': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"update_cells\" at 'requests[0]': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Any help on where to go from here would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The write range is truncated to the size of the sheet, and the sheet is only 1000 rows. You'll need to increase the number of rows in the sheet using an UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest or InsertDimensionRequest first.  (It can be in the same batchUpdateSpreadsheet call.)

That's a pretty misleading error message, though, so I'll look into making that better.

Comment: After doing that, I got a HTTP Code of 502.

Comment: Is it possible to upload a CSV and then have it automatically converted to Google sheets?

Comment: What was the error message with the 502?  And you can use the drive API to convert a CSV I believe.

Comment: Error 502 (Server Error)!!1 -- HTML was returned and that was the title of the HTML document.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using that generates the 502?

Comment: Thank you @SamBerlin! For the record, I manage to create several sheets with number of rows > 1000 but it only fails occasionally o_O ... Anyway, safer to always set the size beforehand!

Comment: @William -- sorry for the delayed reply, I didn't realize you changed the question to give more information about the 502.  See the PHP example @ https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate#example for more details about how to construct a PHP BatchUpdateSpreadsheet request.  (I'm assuming you're using PHP based on your code sample.)